# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

```
#! usr/bin python3
import csv
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()


reader = csv.reader(open("urls.csv"))
for row in reader:
    print (row)

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    search = soup.find('div', class_='search-total js-search-total')
    span = soup.find('span', class_='search-message js-page-title')
    spantext = span.text
    searchtext = search.text
    print(spantext, searchtext)

    save (searchtext, spantext, 'project.csv')

def save(searchtext, spantext, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Название', 'Кол-во'))
        writer.writerow((spantext, searchtext))
def main():
    parse(get_html('http://www.abitant.com/catalogues/bra-i-nastennye-svetilniki/companies/robers'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу.

В urls.csv в первой колонке находятся урлы.

```
for row in reader:
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode

```
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Comment: Что-нибудь напечатать на экран успевает до ошибки? Если нет, первую строку `urls.csv` приведите, плз. Да, и в какой кодировке `urls.csv` сохранен?

Comment: Можно также попробовать вместо `print(row)` `for item in row: print(item)`. Как ни странно, может помочь.

Comment: следует приводить полный traceback, не нужно его обрезать.

Answer (score 2):

`open("urls.csv")` в Питоне 3 декодирует текст из `urls.csv`, используя `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` кодировку по умолчанию, которая в вашем случае `utf-8`.

Ошибка указывает, что `urls.csv` не закодирован в utf-8 -- не всякая последовательность байт может быть интерпретирована как текст в utf-8 кодировке. Выясните какую кодировку на самом деле использует `urls.csv` файл и передайте её в `open()` явно:

```
with open('urls.csv', newline='', encoding='настоящая кодировка') as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        print(*map(ascii, row))
```

Можно `errors` параметр передать, чтобы указать каким образом ошибки, связанные с кодировкой символов, следует обрабатывать, например, `'ignore'` или `'surrogateescape'`.

Answer (score 0):

В питоне весьма странная поддержка utf-8. Вышеуказанная проблема решается вот таким заголовком

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

(в Вашем заголовке хэшбэнг неверно написан.)

Comment: Неа, не помогло.
Ошибка та же.

Comment: @Kovadim, Это же 3-й питон, там вроде все ОК  с Юникодом.

Comment: все ок в 3.4, а в младше проблема есть.

Comment: протестил у себя - проблема не воспроизводиться.

Возникает вопрос - а какая ось используется?

Comment: OS Ubuntu XFCE 

Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux

Comment: может покажете файл "urls.csv" ?

И, кстати, `echo $LANG` что показывает? (запускать в консоли)

Comment: Там, похоже, именно в цсв-шнике проблема. Кстати, 0x8b = 131 - как минимум не ASCII.

Comment: └─ $ ▶ echo $LANG
ru_RU.UTF-8

Comment: Проблему с кодировкой так и не удалось решить,
зато с *.txt проблем не возникает

Comment: (1) utf-8 является кодировкой по умолчанию для исходного кода на Питоне 3 (поэтому `coding:utf-8` бесполезен здесь) (2) внешние файлы такие как `urls.csv` не являются частью исходного кода, поэтому указывать `coding:utf-8` совершенно бесполезно, при проблемах с чтением из urls.csv.

Comment: 1) в 3.4 питоне - да, в 3.3 ещё проглючивало. 
2) у автора не проблема с чтением, а проблема с печатью. смотрим внимательно где именно ругается
3) есть подозрение, что сам файл urls.csv битый. И тут не поможет никакое указание кодировки. 0x8b - это не utf-8.

Comment: ваш  комментарий указывает, что вы не понимаете как с Юникодом работать. Каждый пункт или не имеет отношения к вопросу или ошибочен.

Comment: если о первом ещё можно подискутировать, то по второму и третьему Вы абсолютно неправы. Вполне возможно, что Вы сами плохо почитали вопрос и сделали преждевременные выводы.

Comment: @KoVadim: если вы хотите, чтобы я получил оповещение, используйте `@` синтакс. А по поводу комментария, я даже не знаю что сказать: Вы опытный участник, а настаиваете в теме, в которой очевидно ничего не понимаете (*нормально не знать что-то*, но продолжать настаивать, когда Вам указали на ошибки -- не понимаю). (1) Вы рекомендуете бесполезное указание кодировки исходного кода (с помощью `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`), которое не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу. (2) *"у автора не проблема с чтением, а проблема с печатью"* -- Вы не понимаете, что `UnicodeDecodeError` означает...

Comment: ... (3) *"И тут не поможет никакое указание кодировки"* -- нельзя категорично утверждать, например, файл может быть в cp1251 кодировке (или какой-нибудь другой). Мы знаем, что utf-8 не работает, но не знаем подойдёт ли какая-либо другая кодировка.