# Проблема с чтением данных из файла с кириллицей

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, кириллица

Я работаю с CGI скриптом на Python3.

Мне нужно прочитать CSV файл с кириллицей.
Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
 with open('db.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

Когда в CSV файле нет кириллицы, все отлично, как только появляется один символ, возникает ошибка.

> UnicodeEncodeError: ‘ascii’ codec can't encode character ‘\u0440’ in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Я перепробовал множество вариантов с декодерами, но лишь получал другие ошибки. 
Исходная запись делается в utf8

UPD После обращения к хостеру (sweb.ru), выяснилось вот что:

> mod_wsgi настроен на работу именно python 2.7.5, использование 
>   mod_wsgi с python 3.4 не представляется возможным.

Так что проблема с кодировкой в их технической отсталости, а не в коде.

Comment: попробуйте: `open('db.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') `

Comment: @MaxU: 1- у автора `UnicodeEncodeError`, а не `UnicodeDecodeError`. Обратите внимание: encode vs. decode. Код в вопросе вообще ни той ни другой ошибки не может выбросить. Ошибка возникает в коде, который не приведён. Автору следует полный traceback привести, чтобы ясно было какая строчка ошибку выбрасывает (`LC_ALL=C python3 -c "print('\u0440')"`) 2- Если бы была бы ошибка с чтением, то следовало бы использовать: [`open('db.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8')` для чтения csv файла в Питоне 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471570/23044). Обратите внимание: `newline=''`

Comment: В начале файла: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: @jfs, да, не обратил внимание на "Encode"...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич декларация кодировки влияет только на константы в исходном коде. Это не имеет никакого отношения к кодировке csv-файла, кодировке из локали, кодировке ввода/вывода.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что во всем виноват хостер. Я написал в саппорт и получил ответ: На наших серверах mod_wsgi веб-сервера Apache использует версию python 2.7.5.

Вам необходимо настроить cgi-оболочку python.cgi, где будет указан путь до нужной версии интерпретатора:

#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/python3.4

и подключать ее в файле .htaccess:

php_flag engine off
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/w/wipartcom/xtestx/public_html/cgi-bin/"
AddType application/x-httpd-python .py
Action  application/x-httpd-python /cgi-bin/python.cgi

Comment: @exister будет полезным научиться писать код, который работает в обоих питонах. В данном случае можно написать `import io; with io.open('db.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') ...` — такой код будет работать и в 3.4 у вас, и в 2.7 у sweb.